FORM NOT POSTED (EXPRESS.JS)
i tried submitting the form but it aint working
<% layout('layout/boilerplate') %>

<div class="row">
  <h1 class="text-center">New Event</h1>
  <div class="col-6 offset-3">
    <form action="/events" method="POST" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="EventName">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="EventName" id="EventName" required>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="EventLocation">Location</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="EventLocation" id="EventLocation" required>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="EventDate">Date</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="EventDate" id="EventDate" required>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="EventTime">Time</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="time" name="EventTime" id="EventTime" required>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="EventDescription">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="EventDescription" id="EventDescription" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="EventEligibility">Eligibility</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="EventEligibility" id="EventEligibility" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="EventOrganiserName">Organiser Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="EventOrganiserName" id="EventOrganiserName">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="EventOrganiserEmail">Organiser Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="EventOrganiserEmail" id="EventOrganiserEmail">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Create Event</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <a href="/events">All events</a>
  </div>
</div>

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');
const path = require('path');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const { pool, getEvents, getEvent, createEvent } = require('./database'); // Import pool and functions
const cors = require("cors");
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors("*"));
app.get('/events', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const events = await getEvents();
        res.render('events/index', { events });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error fetching events:", err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch events' });
    }
});

app.get('/events/new', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('events/new');
});
app.post('/events', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Received form data:', req.body); // Log the request body
    try {
        const eventData = {
            EventName: req.body.EventName,
            EventDate: req.body.EventDate,
            EventTime: req.body.EventTime,
            EventLocation: req.body.EventLocation,
            EventDescription: req.body.EventDescription,
            EventEligibility: req.body.EventEligibility,
            EventOrganiserName: req.body.EventOrganiserName || 'NOT SET',
            EventOrganiserEmail: req.body.EventOrganiserEmail || 'NOT SET'
        };
        const eventId = await createEvent(eventData);
        res.redirect(`/events/${eventId}`); // Redirect to event details page
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating event:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating event' });
    }
});


app.get('/temp', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('events/temp');
});
app.get('/events/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const eventId = req.params.id;
    try {
        const event = await getEvent(eventId);
        if (event.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Event not found' });
        }
        res.render('events/show', { event: event[0] });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error fetching event:", err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Error fetching event" });
    }
});

app.listen(3030, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3030');
});


i tried submitting the form the payload looks like this

but the req.body is empty at the post side no idea what to do.
i cant seem to submit the question its tiresome and frustrating to be honest
hey common just allow me to submit already

Have you tried using Postman or Curl to see whether the issue is with the form or the server endpoint? Once you determine which side you're having issues with, it will be easier to help you.

You're not using the middleware for multipart/form-data. Why are you using that option in the first place. It's only needed when you're uploading files.

Does the form submits and you are not getting data or form is not submitting?Have you tested this with Postman or in browser ?

well i had intentions to include files.hence multipart-form data
Also the form submits but I don't receive nothin at the end point .. The payload image is the data being passed..i tried console.log(req.bosy) at endpoint but it returned {}
